# Probabilities, with replacement

Tags: statistics

I have a question, and here it's:

Three cards are drawn with replacement. What is the probability that at least one of the three cards is a king?

i'm not sure if I can solve it without your help.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that "at least one of the three cards is a king" is the same as $1 - {}$"the probability that none of the three cards is a king" (the two events are opposite).

Now (I assume there are $4$ kings and $52$ cards in the deck), since we're drawing with replacement, the probability that none of the three cards is a king is $\frac{48}{52} \cdot \frac{48}{52} \cdot \frac{48}{52} = {\left(\frac{48}{52}\right)}^3$ by the multiplication rule.

Hence, the result is $1 - {\left(\frac{48}{52}\right)}^3$.

Comment: thanks,
so final answer is equal to 1-0.7866=0.2134 ?!

Comment: @Murat: Yes indeed.